# Python pip installer not controlling versions of packages

Tags: python, pip

I ran into a version control issue regarding pip (Python 2.7.14).  I updated pip to version 20.3.3.  And then installed python packages.  I specified the versions for each package.  The issue arose when installing sympy, version 1.3 (command line code shown below):

`C:\Python27\python.exe C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe install --no-cache-dir sympy==1.3`

sympy installs mpmath, version 0.19, as a dependency.  pip proceeds to say it is downloading mpmath version 0.19, but then attempts to install version 1.2.1.  pip then returns an error, stating that the install has failed.  The issue can be worked around by first installing mpmath directly, version 0.19, and then proceeding to install sympy, version 1.3.  Since the mpmath dependency is already satisfied, sympy skips trying to download and install mpmath.  sympy is then able to install successfully.

Is there a way to control the version of dependencies when pip installs them from other packages?  I would like to be able to control all versions to ensure my software produces the same results over time.

Comment: *"Is there a way to control the version of dependencies when pip installs them from other packages?"* See the optional `requirements.txt` file a package may have. Not aware of a reliable way (unless you were to hack `requirements.txt` of your target package). What I do if I manually want to guarantee a specific version of a dependency package is installed: `pip install mypath==0.19`

Comment: This is almost surely a duplicate, see related questions on [*pip requirements.txt version dependency*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pip+requirements.txt+version+dependency)

Comment: Thank you for your input smci.  My concern is that my installer package was working fine for several years now by specifying the version of necessary packages.  mpmath was a dependency of sympy (mpmath is not directly imported in my software, whereas sympy is directly imported).  But now, out of the blue, when re-installing the software sympy failed to install due to an issue with pip not controlling (seemingly) the version of a dependency (mpmath) of sympy.  I am hoping to avoid similar issues popping up in the future when others use the software.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try `pip-tools`: https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools

All you have to do is writing a `requirements.in` file where you can pin the first level dependencies (`sympy` in your case).

You then run `pip-compile requirements.in`: a `requirements.txt` will be generated automatically with all the dependencies pinned as well.

Comment: Upon closer inspection, sympy 1.3 has the mpmath dependency defined as mpmath >= 0.19.  So I think this solution will result in the same issue - the problem appears to be with sympy's dependency specifications (>= rather than ==).  It seems that this issue is not something which can be solved programmatically, but would need to be addressed on an individual basis.  Thank you for your solution though.